# PHP, sorting options from dropdown

Tags: php, sorting

My dropdown has options like this

```
something 4M/512k
something 10M/768k
something 4M/2M
something 10M/5M
something 10M/10M
something 20M/20M (FTTH)
something 60M/60M (FTTH)
something 100M/100M (FTTH)
```

Now the sorting should be like this:Don't look at the something word,first column for the sorting should be 4M or 10M...the value before the / sign.After that the sorting should continue with the second column which is 512k or 2M...but it depends if the value in the second column contains k char(that means kylobytes) should be first(M means megabytes).
And the third column should be FTTH.For example if that row contains (FTTH) word it should be placed last ...

This is the example how it should look like

```
something 4M/512k
something 4M/2M
something 10M/768k
something 10M/5M
something 10M/10M
something 20M/20M (FTTH)
something 60M/60M (FTTH)
something 100M/100M (FTTH)
```

Comment: Then how is the options generated? Cant you just put them in the right order manually? Do you have an array of values? Tell us!

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.php.net/usort to create your own sorting method to sort an array containing your dropdown options.

This should get you a good start:

```
<?php
$data[] = "something 4M/512k";
$data[] = "something 10M/768k";
$data[] = "something 4M/2M";
$data[] = "something 10M/5M";
$data[] = "something 10M/10M";
$data[] = "something 20M/20M (FTTH)";
$data[] = "something 60M/60M (FTTH)";
$data[] = "something 100M/100M (FTTH)";

function mysort($a, $b){
  list($something, $a_speed) = explode(" ", $a);
  list($something, $b_speed) = explode(" ", $b);

  list($a_speed_part_1, $a_speed_part_2) = explode("/", $a_speed);
  list($b_speed_part_1, $b_speed_part_2) = explode("/", $b_speed);

  //TODO: add M/k comparison or calculation

  if(intval($a_speed_part_1) > intval($b_speed_part_1)){
    return 1;
  } elseif (intval($a_speed_part_1) < intval($b_speed_part_1)) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    if(intval($a_speed_part_2) > intval($b_speed_part_2)){
      return 1;
    } elseif (intval($a_speed_part_2) < intval($b_speed_part_2)) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

usort($data, "mysort");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```